# Session in codeigniter not working well

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I can't figure it out what's the actual error with session in Codeigniter. My other project are working well with this code. But in this case, I got problem.

For login session my code is:

```
 $data = array(
               'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
               'admin_logged_in' => true,
               'logged_in' =>true

             );
 $this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

And I check session as:

```
 if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in') == true) { 
     // code
    }
```

Before going to controller I am checking session like above and if session is not true then redirecting to login page.

For logout:

```
 function logout() {
        if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in') == TRUE) {
            $useremail = $this->session->userdata('username');
        $data = array(
                'username' => $useremail,
                'admin_logged_in' => true,
                'logged_in' =>true
            );
        $this->session->unset_userdata($data);
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
     }
  }
```

But above code is not working for me. When I logout, page is successfully redirected to logout page but session is not destroyed since I can access all the page that needs session set. Please help me.

### Updated

I got an strange problem. When I log into the system and logout. And trying to access the method that needs session. I can access if I wrote method name without index.php. And I cannot access method that needs session if I wrote method name with index.php.
Example:
BnW needs session to be set in order to go furthur. 
If I login and logout then, If I write in borwser URL following:

```
 example.com/index.php/bnw      //it redirects to login page.
 example.com/bnw                //it logs in directly.
```

- Does removing `index.php` from .htaccess gives problem with session?

Comment: In your `config.php` file set `$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 0;` and try

Comment: I see your using both unset and destroy just use one or other

Answer (score 0):

Put this `inside your logout function,` it works for me

```
$user_data = $this->session->all_userdata();
        foreach ($user_data as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 'session_id' && $key != 'ip_address' && $key != 'user_agent' && $key != 'last_activity') {
                $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
            }
        }
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
```

Comment: you can access all your session variables after this or some particular session variables ?

Comment: Yes I can access. When I `var_dump` login session name before and after session unset. Its return true before unset and false after unset. But even I can access my contoller's method directly from URL.

Comment: ok  try to expire session dynamically using 
$this->session->sess_expiration = '0';
inside logout function.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Your .htaccess should be (should place outside of application folder)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

in `config/config.php`

if 2.0(line 247)

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 0;
```

if 3.0(line 358)

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 0;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

In controller

```
function logout()
{
    $result = $this->model_name->check_login();
    if ( $result == TRUE )
    {

        if(!empty($log))
        {
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            $this->index();//your logging should be here
        }
        else
        {
            //some code here
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

In Model

```
public function check_login()
{
    $log = $this->session->all_userdata();

    if (isset($log['admin_logged_in']))
    {
        if($log['admin_logged_in'] == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and each and every controller check whether session is set. if set load the view, else direct to index function. So this will prevent user from direct access through URL

*sample code to check log in*

```
$result = $this->model_name->check_login();
if($result==true)
    {
        //load your views as usual
    }
else
    {
        //load index function
        $this->index();
    }
```

Index function(in controller)

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('admin/logging');//load your loginf view here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your `logout()` function, it doesn't go inside the `if` block so the session doesn't get destroyed at all

in the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) it says

> Note: The function returns FALSE (boolean) if the item you are trying
>   to access does not exist.

it doesn't say it returns TRUE

so change

```
if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in') == TRUE)
```

to

```
if ($this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in') != FALSE)
```

and check your session  if it is really destroyed after `sess_destroy()`

```
 $this->session->sess_destroy();
 $admin_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged_in');
 echo "-----------------> $admin_logged_in";
```